# Eclipse doesn't find my device

Tags: android, eclipse

I've updated everything. No problem with driver. Added android:debuggable="true" to the . USB debugging mode on. But still dont work. My OS is Win7, my device is Huawei.

[image]

Comment: Hey Refer this link for the solution... http://androidbysravan.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-check-our-android-app-in-our.html

Comment: u need to execute the command in command prompt that "chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" this is the path of ur drive where in 51-android.rules u need to paste this line::SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

Comment: Which device are you trying to attach?

Answer (score 6):

- Make sure, that your usb connection
  type is "**Charge only**",
- disable and the enable the **USB
  debugging** on your device (`Menu->Settings->Applications->Development->USB debugging` **uncheck** `->` **check**),

and Eclipse should recognize it.

**Update**
I also have to close the emulator window (if I have running any), and this works for me all the time.

Comment: How to check that "usb connection type is "Charge only"" ? Thanks .

Comment: Clicking on the USB notification icon does the trick. (At least on my ICS)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of checking that the USB connection type was "Charge only", when I was going to check that I noticed that my device was switched off completely.

Comment: A little different for my phone - Settings > Developer Options > USB Debugging == check. The device appeared immediately on Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Check the USB-to-microUSB cable. I was using one that I suspect only charges battery power, but no data transmission. After changing to another cable, my phone successfully appeared under android device in the eclipse run window.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I had been trying for an hour on my Mac OS. Reset adb, ran Eclipse as admin, everything. I changed the cable and voila! It works.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project, select 'Run As Configuration'. then Select 'Android Application' ->you application and from 'target tab' uncheck all emulators. After this, make sure all emulators are down and then right click on your application and 'Run As' -> Android Application'. it will show you the option to select your device as target.

Comment: If you have android project and you right click and select'Run As' , you should see 'Android Application' and 'Run Configuration' options.Else some other problem exists.

Comment: Right click on project, Run As -> Configuration -> Android Tab -> There is no emulator list to uncheck?

Comment: I ran my project hundreds of times times before, but after a reboot it suddenly "forgot" some configuration!? This tip helped though.

Answer (score 1):

is your phone in development mode? settings --> applications --> USB debugging

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart adb server , run

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

from command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that driver installed successfully, open device manager and find your device driver installed.
install your device software (like Kies in case of Samsung mobiles) it will install drivers automatically

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed the  USB driver for the device.

Answer (score 0):

I've meet this situation many times before , there's some workaround about this. :

- unplug the cable and then plug in
  again
- restart your device, or
- restart your computer

that way the device will online again.

Answer (score 0):

For other people having the same problem. I have the same problem before and tried all solution but the problem remain the same until I check the Device Manager and under Universal Serial Bus controllers, once I plug-in the device and I got an 'Unknown Device' in the list. So, my solution is remove the unknown driver, scan the hardware and reinstall the driver for my device and now is working. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got a problem with your driver 
Try installing your driver from [HERE](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Spent time looking for my device under 'Debug' - Devices are found under 'Run'.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from a different angle:
Type "adb devices" in terminal (the executable is in platform-tools directory of Android SDK).
If the output shows that the device exists, this may be related to the project you are trying to run (if not then the device is not installed correctly, driver issue). If the device's Android version is lower than the project's minimum version (see AndroidManifest.xml file look for android:minSdkVersion), the device will not appear in the launch window. Try a lower number for android:minSdkVersion than the one specified which is smaller or uquals your device's version. Please take in account that this may cause the app to crash if your device does not support the API used in the project.