# Android Motorola ET1 Tablet DEVICE NOT DETECTING IN ADT-IDE

Tags: java, android, windows-8, adt, eclipse-adt

I trying to connect and  debug my application with ET1 MOTROLO device with ADT ,but the device is not detecting, other devices such as asus  tablets and phones are detecting and i am able to debug ,but for this  motrola tablet its not detecting.
I changed and  configured as
per this link https://docs.symbol.com/ReleaseNotes/ET1N0-ADB_Setup_Instruction.pdf

My system is  Windows 8 -
yet no luck.If any one have  solved this issue please let me know.
The system  detects the device as a media player and i can browse to the sdcard folder, but IDE Does not detects the tablet when debug or running my application

Comment: please visit this [link][1] and [this][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824531/eclipse-doesnt-recognize-my-android-device
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987316/eclipse-doesnt-find-my-device

Comment: I tried  that link , yet couldn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Hi android developers for motorola Solutions (Enterprice Edition devices )-
I found the Driver for Et1 MOTROLO Device   from here and solved this issue
Download the exe and install as per the below link, and then surely adt will detect the Motorola device for enterprise edition Android such as ET1-Android Tablet ,MC 40 and TC55.

Click [here](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN)!

you can download this from Motorola Solutions support site and search for "Android USB driver".

Currently last version is 1.1 that covers ET1, MC40 and TC55.

DOWNLOAD HERE
 [DOWNLOAD EXE](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=92183&redirectForm=search&searchQuery=%3FsearchType%3Dsimple%26searchTerm%3DAndroid%20USB%20driver)!

[DOWNLOAD UPDATED  EXE ANDROID USB DRIVER V1.2](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=95914)!